# Add another character not existing in table when export to text file

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I create a procedure to export data to text file. It be like:

```
'bcp "select name,age,grade from test" queryout C:\test.txt
```

however i want to add some other character like |. And output file content would be like:
Jones|6 C.
Which is the most convenient way to do that. Should i create a temporary table?

Comment: you mean use `|` as seperator ? use a `BCP` format file

Comment: @Squirrel that's such a good answer. I never think about that solution. so my command should be 
'bcp "select name,age,grade from test" -i test.fmt queryout C:\test.txt 
Is it right?

Comment: should be `-f test.fmt`

Comment: Ok. i'll try. Thank you

Comment: @Squirrel what if in my command already have replicate function. Example:
Select name, replicate (''0'',2-len(age)),age,grade

Comment: not sure what you mean. What is the issue here ?

Comment: @NguyenVanHung if you have replicate, then subselect it. (meaning contain it in a subquery)

Answer (score 2):

You can concatenate the fields in the query:

```
select name + '|' + cast(age as varchar(255)), grade
from test
```

I'm not 100% sure if this gives the results you want.  You *can* put all the fields into a single string, which may be simpler than using a format file.

Or, you can use `-t` if the intention is to put a field terminator of `|` between each field.  This is all covered in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/specify-field-and-row-terminators-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017#characters-supported-as-terminators) (which admittedly is a bit verbose making it hard to find anything).